# How to find a space in a text. using grep?

Tags: grep

How to grep one space in text ?

```
cat a.txt| grep ' '
```

or

```
cat a.txt| grep '\s '
```

Comment: Gratuitous use of `cat` in both cases.  The first could be written `grep ' ' a.txt`, the second altered similarly.

Comment: Note that `\s` also matches tab, return, vertical tab, form feed and, technically, newline. If you want to only match space and tab, use `[[:blank:]]` or `[ \t]`.

Comment: using gnu grep, you can limit number of matches (`-m` option) to one...

Comment: This is more simple
egrep "\s" a.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found it:

```
grep  "\+[[:space:]]\+" a.xml
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to grep for just one space as you put in your question, you would use something like:

```
grep -e '^\s[^\s]' -e '[^\s]\s$' -e '[^\s]\s[^\s]' a.txt
```

or for POSIX variants:

```
grep -e '^ [^ ]' -e '[^ ] $' -e '[^ ] [^ ]' a.txt
```

or the less readable POSIX variant:

```
grep '\(^\|[^ ]\)\ \([^ ]\|$)' a.txt
```

Assuming you want to exclude lines that contain more than one adjacent space, this explicitly requires there be one space, not preceded by a space and not followed by a space.

Also, it's worth noting that not all versions of grep support '\s' regular expression controls.

Comment: You can omit all those backslashes from the last example and improve readability by using the POSIX-specified `-E` option which enables extended regexes. `grep -E '(^|[^ ]) ([^ ]|$)' a.txt` In any case, the backslash before the space isn't needed and there's one missing before the final closing parenthesis. Also, for versions of `grep` that understand `\s`, you can shorten the expression for non-space `[^\s]` to `\S`

Comment: However this works too , [[:blank:]]

Answer (score 1):

Variant 2 will only find two spaces. If you use `'\s'` instead, both variants will work.

You could easily test this yourself, so what's your actual question?

Comment: Why only find two spaces? I think it match any space.

Comment: @Gnouc: Variant 2 as he wrotes it `'\s '` will match at least two spaces in a row, because he added a space character after the character group `\s`.

Comment: You're right, I don't see the space after `\s`, my mistake.